# Xcode Archive Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, archive

When i try to archive me app in Xcode, it gives me an error that i don't have a provisioning profile. how do i get one. i have an IOS Development account.
 I tried to upload a distribution certificate, but it did not work. why?

The Error says...

XCode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues.

you account already had a valid IOS Distribution certificate

visit member center or import developer profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certificates and there are profiles, they are two different things.  It sounds like you have a distribution certificate.  Go to the developer portal, and then go the the identities, certificates, and profiles.

Profiles will be at the bottom.  You need a distribution profile for your app id.  Distribution profiles are then signed by distribution certificates.  It is pretty straightforward.  Once you create the profile, download it and double click it to add it to your library.